# FireFTP - URL with Login

Tags: mozilla, sftp

on successful connection to an SFTP site, FireFTP has an oprion to copy 'URL with Login'; this provides a fully qualified URL with all credentials used in accessing the FTP site.

I am assuming that this URL can be used elsewhere: {Where} Can I use the URL to navigate to the site automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used for multiple purposes.
- You can easily save the credentials to a file
- You can easily send the credentials to a friend 
- You can use it to navigate to it from browser
- You can use it to store 
- And if somebody else uses your pc, not everybody can access the ftp, because you don't need to "save" the credentials in the application itself.

So i believe it is more of a 'use it for your own wishes' thing.

Edit: Mozilla says: 'FireFTP will copy the URL (HTTP or FTP) and put it in the clipboard so you can paste it somewhere.'

See:
http://fireftp.mozdev.org/help.html